# the getter 'text' was called on null flutter

Tags: flutter, variables, dart, controller, null

I have this error in my Flutter app:

> **NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'text' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: text
>   See also:
>   https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    NewApp()
  );
}

class NewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  NewApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewAppState createState() => _NewAppState();
}

class _NewAppState extends State<NewApp> {
  TextEditingController textController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
       child: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           TextField(
            controller: textController,
          ),
          Text(
            textController.text
          )
         ],
       )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Normally you should explain what you have tried to solve it, but I alas I feel this error is quite vague. In a perfect world the error would say "textController has not been initialized"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have not initialized your `TextEditingController`. You can initialize it at the time of declaring it like this,

```
TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
```

It is essential to initialize it before using it otherwise the instance `textController` remains null and `textController.text` is called on null.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `textController` is not yet instantiated, hence its value is `null`. You can make the property call null-aware to skip the error:

```
textController?.text
```

you'll get other errors though. After fixing the other errors the app will work but I doubt it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of errors in there, so i ll just post the whole, working code. You were missing a MaterialApp and Scaffold Widget. These are required for your App to run (Scaffold is required on every screen).

As for your TextController, you have to check if the controller exists, and if the controller.text has a value, otherwise you try to assign null when your widget is expecting a String. I solved that with a ternery expression here.

`condition ? if yes block : if no block`

Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(NewApp());
}

class NewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  NewApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewAppState createState() => _NewAppState();
}

class _NewAppState extends State<NewApp> {
  TextEditingController textController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: textController,
            ),
            Text(textController != null && textController.text != null
                ? textController.text
                : "")
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```